# ResourceNotFoundException using Spinner

Tags: android, dialog, spinner

I would like to create a customized popup dialog which contains a spinner. The dialog needs to be launched from an Adapter class, below is my code:

```
 Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);
 dialog.setContentView(R.layout.myPopup);
 Spinner spinner = (Spinner)dialog.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
 ArrayAdapter<String> arrayadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext, 0);
 arrayadapter.add("AddSomeStrings");
 spinner.setAdapter(arrayadapter);
 dialog.show();
```

This code is executed fine, but sometime after the "show()", I see an exception: Resources$NotFoundException. The last item in the callstack is Resources.loadXmlResourceParser. If I don't assign the spinner using findViewById, but instead assign it via spinner = new Spinner(dialog.getContext()), then I don't get the error (but then of course I cannot see my dialog).

myPopup layout contains:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/layout_root"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:padding="10dp"
          >
  <Spinner 
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:prompt="@string/group_prompt"
     />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Any thoughts what I am doing wrong? thanks!

Comment: could it be that the context of the arrayadapter should be the dialog and not the activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your using the array adapter with Constructor Context and TextView ID, but your just passing it 0 as the text view resource id.

See the API here : [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int%29)

Try:

```
  ArrayAdapter<String> arrayadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

or other resource of you choice